# how to concatenate all input strings and print the output in java

Tags: java, string, input, concatenation

I only found this but it's not working, i'll be very thankful if someone helps me because i'm new to java and it's getting me mad lol:

```
public class ConcatenateStrings {
    public static String concateLines(String[] s, String separator) {
        String result = "";  
        if (s.length > 0) {  
            result = s[0];    // start with the first element  
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {  
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(result);  
                sb.append(separator);  
                sb.append(s[i]);  
                result = sb.toString();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new `StringBuilder` every time.

```
public class ConcatenateStrings {
    public static String concateLines(String[] s, String separator) {
        String result = "";  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (s.length > 0) {  
            sb.append(s[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {        
                sb.append(separator);  
                sb.append(s[i]);  
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 String[] input = {"Test", "input"};
 System.out.println(ConcatenateStrings.concateLines(input, ","));
}
```

Or with user input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println(ConcatenateStrings.concateLines(args, ","));
}
```

As you can see, you can even drop the `result` variable.

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class ConcatenateStrings, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Do you have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Comment: no..i just tried to check ur code, but didn't work.

Comment: @user2984458: you need a `main` method to execute your code. See the example I have provided in an edit.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel There's a typo in your code. When `s.length` is equal to `0`, you try to return `sb.toString()`, but `sb` is out of scope.

Comment: thanks it works just fine. But, I want to let the client enter the input not me.

Comment: Then you'll need to look at the `Scanner` class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: are you sure that I need the scanner? isn't there a simple way without?
and thanks alot bro!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. A `Scanner` is used to let the user input data in a console.

Comment: i don't want in a console, just arguments.